# ffmpeg HEVC mp4 to HLS stream

Tags: hls

I'm using ffmpeg -f hls option to create multiple resolutions from 1 single mp4 source

it works fine on all browsers with video.js with regular h.264 source mp4.

however throwing HEVC HDR source (e.g. https://4kmedia.org/sony-food-fizzle-uhd-hdr-4k-demo/) will result into something NOT playable in Safari

```
ffmpeg -i ../sample4k-hdr.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=7[v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7]; \
[v1]scale=426:240[v1out]; \
[v2]scale=640:360[v2out]; \
[v3]scale=854:480[v3out]; \
[v4]scale=1280:720[v4out]; \
[v5]scale=1920:1080[v5out]; \
[v6]scale=2560:1440[v6out]; \
[v7]scale=3840:2160[v7out]" \
-map "[v1out]" -c:v:0 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:0 500k -maxrate:v:0 500k -minrate:v:0 500k -bufsize:v:0 1000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map "[v2out]" -c:v:1 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:1 1000k -maxrate:v:1 1000k -minrate:v:1 1000k -bufsize:v:1 2000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map "[v3out]" -c:v:2 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:2 1500k -maxrate:v:2 1500k -minrate:v:2 1500k -bufsize:v:2 3000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map "[v4out]" -c:v:3 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:3 3000k -maxrate:v:3 3000k -minrate:v:3 3000k -bufsize:v:3 6000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map "[v5out]" -c:v:4 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:4 5000k -maxrate:v:4 5000k -minrate:v:4 5000k -bufsize:v:4 10000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map "[v6out]" -c:v:5 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:5 9000k -maxrate:v:5 9000k -minrate:v:5 9000k -bufsize:v:5 18000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map "[v7out]" -c:v:6 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:6 30000k -maxrate:v:6 30000k -minrate:v:6 30000k -bufsize:v:6 60000k -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 48k \
-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 64k \
-map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 96k \
-map a:0 -c:a:3 aac -b:a:3 128k \
-map a:0 -c:a:4 aac -b:a:4 192k \
-map a:0 -c:a:5 aac -b:a:5 384k \
-map a:0 -c:a:6 aac -b:a:6 384k \
-flags +cgop \
-movflags +faststart \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-color_trc bt709 \
-color_primaries bt709 \
-colorspace bt709 \
-tag:v hvc1 \
-ac 2 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 2 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_segment_filename stream_%v/data%02d.ts \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3 v:4,a:4 v:5,a:5 v:6,a:6" stream_%v.m3u8
```

I've tried using libx265 main, and differ h264 profile: baseline, main, high, high10 and etc without success. Some will produce no video but just audio.

Also tried with videotoolbox on macos and nvenc on ubuntu without success.

So is it possible to maintain the quality with libx264 or h264_nvenc or h264_videotoolbox during the HLS transcoding?

1. HEVC to HLS
2. HEVC HDR to HLS

if yes, what should be the params & profile to use?
if no, can it be done with h265, and with which params & profile?

cheers